# Ruby - reddit oauth returns 404

Tags: ruby, oauth, httparty, reddit

I'm trying to get an auth token from reddit using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). I'm using reddit's script authentication which is explained [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example).

The curl version from that page looks like this. If I enter my details in this then it works correctly and returns the authentication token.

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=reddit_bot&password=snoo' --user 'p-jcoLKBynTLew:gko_LXELoV07ZBNUXrvWZfzE3aI' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

Here is my ruby code with the auth implementation that isn't working.

```rb
require 'httparty'
require 'logger'

class Reddit
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://reddit.com'
  logger ::Logger.new("httparty.log"), :debug, :curl

  def initialize(client_id, client_secret, username, password, user_agent)
    @auth = { username: client_id, password: client_secret }
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @user_agent = user_agent
  end

  def authenticate()
    options = { 
      basic_auth: @auth,
      body: { grant_type: 'password', username: @username, password: @password }, 
      headers: { 'User-Agent' => @user_agent }
    }
    self.class.post('/api/v1/access_token', options)
  end
end
```

Here is my log

```
D, [2016-07-21T20:21:29.581864 #10739] DEBUG -- : [HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] > POST /api/v1/access_token
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] > User-Agent: MY_USER_AGENT
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] > grant_type=password&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] > 
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < HTTP/1.1 301
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 19:21:29 GMT
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Transfer-encoding: chunked
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Connection: close
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Set-cookie: __cfduid=d1653e1497aa10c1e9b5c9c1e65027f841469128889; expires=Fri, 21-Jul-17 19:21:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.reddit.com; HttpOnly
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Location: https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < X-content-type-options: nosniff
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Server: cloudflare-nginx
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < Cf-ray: 2c6104281c703500-LHR
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:29 +0100] < 

D, [2016-07-21T20:21:30.930118 #10739] DEBUG -- : [HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] > GET https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] > User-Agent: MY_USER_AGENT
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] > Cookie: __cfduid=d1653e1497aa10c1e9b5c9c1e65027f841469128889
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] > grant_type=password&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] > 
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < HTTP/1.1 404
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 19:21:30 GMT
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Content-length: 38
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Connection: close
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-content-type-options: nosniff
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-ua-compatible: IE=edge
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Access-control-allow-origin: *
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Access-control-expose-headers: X-Reddit-Tracking, X-Moose
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-reddit-tracking: https://pixel.redditmedia.com/pixel/of_destiny.png?v=cPS4SYC7eYS7PUX%2B4OpG5Vd8whFwi9HO%2Btj9EkiJOG%2BX0pPXV71coHXAWrCRqDNvm8svDX3GBsMwOXsOxbGTRaDC%2BRJqtSoM
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < X-moose: majestic
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Server: cloudflare-nginx
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < Cf-ray: 2c61042b711c3470-LHR
[HTTParty] [2016-07-21 20:21:30 +0100] < 
{"message": "Not Found", "error": 404}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you hit a 301 redirect from https://reddit.com to https://www.reddit.com with the initial request.

When HTTParty follows the redirect, it does a GET request instead of a POST (as it should).

Try setting your `base_uri` to 'https://www.reddit.com' instead.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense now. Thank you very much!